# "I'll give him (a? the?) wonderful name, Macavity"

Tags: articles

I am (almost) sure, it would be correct to say this

> "I'll give him *a* wonderful name"

or

> "I'll give him  *the* famous name Macavity"

But what about these?

> "I'll give him (a? the?) wonderful name, Macavity"
>
> "I'll give him (a? the?) wonderful name, viz. Macavity"?

Comment: Does the name "Macavity" already exist before you give him that name?

Comment: I think all sentences with both articles can be correct in specific context.

Comment: @TRomano, Suppose, it does (I don't feel the difference).

Comment: I wasn't sure if you were trying to refer to a situation where a new name was being coined (e.g. by Eliot) or if you were understanding that name to exist already. If the name didn't already exist (and if you were not being ironic) you couldn't say "the famous name, Macavity" because the adjective following the definite article is also definite.You would have to say something like "I will give him the name Macavity, which will be famous someday" or "I will give him the soon-to-be famous name, Macavity".

Comment: Also, you can  use **the** only with a name that already exists. But the test for existence is not stringent. The name needs to exist merely in the speaker's mind.  If you use **the** with a name your listener has never heard of before (because you just made the name up) you're expecting the listener to understand that you just made the name up when you use "**the** name {X}"; you are not expecting the listener to think the name does exist but is simply one he is unfamiliar with. You are conferring existence upon the name by fiat. We all have the power to name a cat whatever we like.

Comment: "I will name him {X}" creates no expectations about the name's previous existence, whereas "I will give him **the** name {X}..." creates an expectation that the name about to be spoken already exists.

Comment: Are you saying that if I meant something else, I would have to write "**a** wonderful  name" in the 3d case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first two surmises are exactly correct.  The third one must be **the**, and the 4th one **a**.

The reason why the 4th one is **a** is, as you probably already know, because the "videlicet" (viz.) breaks the sentence and makes the first clause **independent**.  It can stand by itself as a well-formed sentence, and since it's **indefinite** in construction (the specific name doesn't appear til the dependent clause), it needs **a**.

(You don't need the comma after "name" in sentence 3, but it's okay -- just a bit Germanic-looking)

Comment: What's "Germanic" about the comma?

Comment: German writing looks like Colonial-era English writing:  lots more commas than are common in English writing today.